# What language is this? (Bootcamp, Compass and Sass)

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm doing unit testing with [Bootcamp](https://github.com/thejameskyle/bootcamp). In official Bootcamp tutorial there is an example testing suit. It gives you three files:

functions/math

```
@function power($base, $exponent) {
  $result: 1;

  @if $exponent >= 0 {
    @for $i from 1 through $exponent {
      $result: $result * $base;
    }
  } @else {
    @for $i from $exponent to 0 {
      $result: $result / $base;
    }
  }

  @return $result;
}
```

specs/math.scss

```
@include describe("Math Power") {
  @include it("should expect positive values to be calculated correctly") {
    @include should( expect( power( 10, 2) ), to( equal(  100 )));
    @include should( expect( power(  2, 2) ), to( equal(    4 )));
    @include should( expect( power(0.5, 2) ), to( equal( 0.25 )));
  }

  @include it("should expect negative values to be calculated correctly") {
    @include should( expect( power( 10, -2) ), to( equal( 0.01 )));
    @include should( expect( power(  2, -2) ), to( equal( 0.25 )));
    @include should( expect( power(0.5, -2) ), to( equal(    4 )));
  }
}
```

specs.scss

```
@import "functions/math";

@import "bootcamp";
$bc-setting-verbose:  false;
$bc-setting-warnings: false;

@include runner-start;
@import "specs/math";
@include runner-end;
```

I know that number 3 it's only sass, isn't it? But I don't know what language use in numbers 1 and 2. Today I discovered what framework Compass and Framework Bootcamp are and I don't know if what I'm reading it's Compass or Bootcamp.

Comment: Bootcamp and Compass aren't languages.

Comment: Ok. you're right. I just want to know in what are numbers 1 and 2 written.

Answer (score 1):

The language of all three code snippets is Sass. Compass and Bootcamp are frameworks built on the Sass language.

From Bootcamp's readme.md file (https://github.com/thejameskyle/bootcamp):

> Jasmine-style BDD testing written in Sass for Sass.

From Compass' help page (http://compass-style.org/help/):

> Compass is an open-source CSS authoring framework which uses the Sass stylesheet language to make writing stylesheets powerful and easy.